# JQuery Mobile Javascript Complex Equation

Tags: javascript, android, ios, windows, jquery-mobile

I am in need of some help.

I have a stupidly complex piece of math that I need to turn into a javascript equation and it's not working (annoyingly!!).

Basically the sum is:

```
No#1 / No#2 = Result1
Result1 - 1 = Result2
Result2 * 100 = Result3
Result3 rounds up or down - display result.
```

I hope that makes sense.

The code I am using is:

```
var rc1TyreRatio2 = Number(Apperyio("rc1TyreRatio2").val());
var rc1Test1 = Number(Apperyio("rc1Test1").val());
var rc1Test2 = Number(Apperyio("rc1Test2").val());

var rc1Test1 = rc1InterAxle / rc1TyreRatio2;
var rc1Test2 = rc1Test - 1;
var rc1Lead = rc2Test * 100;

Apperyio('rc1Lead').val(rc1Lead.toFixed(2) + "%");
```

The components are standing JQuery Mobile 'textareas' & they are: rc1TyreRatio2 | rc1Test1 | rc1Test2 | rc1Lead.

I know it's in the appery.io platform, it wasn't my first choice, but my client's as they have other stuff hosted there, so I have to work with it, it use's JQM JavaScript just fine,

Any idea's how I can get this working? using just JavaScript and no HTML at all.

Thank you all,
 - Tech-Xcellent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use brackets to do certain calculations that are unique to get a result. You can chain as many brackets with calculations as you want.

i.e

(calculation A = result) * (calculation B = result) / (calculation C = result) + (calculation D = result)

**Example**

```
var noa = 20;
var nob = 10;

var Total = (noa / nob - 1) * 100; 
alert (Math.round(Total))
```

**Result is 100**

if i dint use brackets e.g `var Total = noa / nob - 1 * 100;` the result would show **-98** which is wrong

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/f9g3z4nm/)**

Comment: Thank you,
Using () didn't occur to me. As it's technically 3 calculation's in 1 calculation, would it work the same if I did.

(noa / nob) - 1) * 100;

Please advise?